# The "number of cardinalities" of subsets of a set $X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Given a set $X$, we define an equivalence relation by $A \sim B$ if $\mathrm{card}(A) = \mathrm{card}(B)$, i.e., there exists a bijection $f: A \to B$. I am taking for granted that this does in fact define an equivalence relation on $X$.

The quotient by $\sim$, $X/{\sim}$ is the "set of cardinalities" of subsets of $X$. Is $X$ is finite of set $n$, Then $\mathrm{card}(X/{\sim}) = |X| + 1$. If $X$ has $n$ elements, I can form subsets of sizes $0, 1, \ldots, n$, so there are $n+1$ possible cardinalities.

The case I can't figure out meaningfully is when $X$ is infinite. Is this answer "provably unknowable" in light of the continuum hypothesis, or is there a way to describe this? The conjecture posed is that $\mathrm{card}(X/{\sim}) = \mathrm{card}(X)$ in such a case, but this seems intuitively false, since $|X| < |\mathcal{P}(X)|$ for any set $X$.

Answer (score 2):

First, a notational point: since $\sim$ is an equivalence relation between subsets of $X$, your "$X/\sim$" should actually be "$\mathcal{P}(X)/\sim$."

As to the main question, your conjecture is false; for example, a set of size $\aleph_{1}$ still has only countably many different sizes of subsets (the finite cardinalities, cardinality $\aleph_0$, and cardinality $\aleph_1$). In general, an infinite set of cardinality $\aleph_\alpha$ has $\aleph_0+\vert\alpha\vert$-many different cardinalities of subsets. The point where independence appears is when we ask about the number of different cardinalities of subsets a set like $\mathbb{R}$, whose cardinality is *not* provably tied to a specific $\aleph$-number.

Comment: +1, and author's conclusion seems to hold when considering infinite sets equivalent to the natural numbers